# The phrase "quantities are connected by the equation of the surface" in Analysis Situs

Tags: manifolds, math-history

I was reading [this](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/poincare2009.pdf) translation of *Analysis Situs* and on the first page (page 15 in the pdf), the following phrase comes up.

> Let $x_1,x_2\dots,x_{n+1}$ be the coordinates of a point on the surface. These
>   $n+ 1$
>   quantities are connected by the equation of the surface.

Is there an implicit assumption that a 'surface' is a variety? Or does the phrase have some other meaning

Comment: Not necessarily.  The equations defining the surface implicitly don't have to be polynomial in Poincare or at least he does not state such an assumption.